# web development application - mac

Tags: macos

Does anyone know of an application (for mac) which will format a page of html code nicely?

ie Open the html file and indent all of the code/blocks, put character returns in and format it into sections so that it is readable rather than being just a big block of code. Then also give the ability to minimize/collapse sections of the code to make it more readable.

I've been trying Coda and Expresso - Expresso has the feature to minimize/collapse code but does not seem to be able to format code.

Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [TACO HTML Edit](http://tacosw.com/)

or

[JEdit](http://www.jedit.org/) (Freeware)

Bye.

Answer (score 4):

[TextMate](http://macromates.com/) is a really cool app. There are hundreds of bundles for all possible languages.

Comment: Although I personally prefer working with Emacs, TextMate meets the questioner's requirements exactly (code folding in Emacs is less than perfect).

Comment: Do you know where the option is to organize the html tags?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [tidy](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/).  I think it is included in OSX (at least the command is there on my system) so you won't need to install anything to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I use [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/) for this.

Comment: I typically stay far away from any software that uses vulgar for promotion.

Answer (score 0):

Textmate will do a nice job.

If you are a java or ruby programmer, [Intellj](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) or [Rubymine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/index.html) does an excellent job of auto-formatting code(including HTML).